# Call child component method from parent in react

Tags: reactjs

I have simple component called **List** which is a simple **ul** with some **li** inside. Each **li** is a simple component.
I have other parent component which render one input field and the **List** component. Tapping on **Send** key I catch text of input field. I want to call for example a function called **handleNewText(inputText)** but this function need to stay inside List component because the state I use to populate other **li** components live in **List** component.

I don' t want to refactor `List` and `MyParent` component passing the manage of data from `List` to `MyParent`.

first is parent and second is child

```js
class TodoComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMpunt(){
    console.log(this._child.someMethod());
  }


  handleKeyPress(event){
    if(event.key === 'Enter'){
      var t = event.target.value;

    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <div>
          <input
            className="inputTodo"
            type="text"
            placeholder="want to be an hero...!"
            onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
          />
          <List/>
        </div>
    );
  }

}


export default class List extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.flipDone = this.flipDone.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      todos: Array(3).fill({ content: '', done: false})
    };
  }

  flipDone(id) {
    let index = Number(id);

    this.setState({
      todos: [
        ...this.state.todos.slice(0, index),
        Object.assign({}, this.state.todos[index], {done: !this.state.todos[index].done}),
        ...this.state.todos.slice(index + 1)
      ]
    });
  }

  render() {

    const myList = this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
      return (
        <Todo key={index}
              clickHandler={this.flipDone}
              id={index}
              todo={todo}
              handleText={this.handleText}
        />
      );
    })

    return (
      <ul className="list">
        {myList}
      </ul>
    );
  }


ReactDOM.render(<TodoComp />,document.getElementById('myList'));
```

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Answer (score 6):

You need to make use of refs to call a function in the child component from the parent component

render the List component from parent as

```
<List ref="myList"/>
```

and then access the `handleNewText()` function  as `this.refs.myList.handleNewText()`

**UPDATE:**

Strings refs are no longer recommended by React, you should rather use ref callbacks, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele/38093981#38093981)

```
<List ref={(ref) => this.myList=ref}/>
```

and then access the child function like

```
this.myList.handleNewText()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Adding to @shubham-khatri solution:

If you are referencing a **connected** child component...

a. That child must say `withRef: true` in the (4th) config parameter:

```
@connect(store => ({
    foo: store.whatever
    …
}),null,null,{ withRef: true })
```

b. Access is through `getWrappedInstance()` (note, that `getWrappedInstance` also needs to be called `()`)

```
getWrappedInstance().howdyPartner()
```

Answer (score 0):

I started learning React when functional component came out.  Another way I experimented with some success is returning functions that you want to access as closures within a JSON.  I like this method because closure is a construct of Javascript and it should still work even if React is updated yet again. Below is an example of child component

```
function Child(){
    //declare your states and use effects
    const [ppp, setPPP] = useState([]);
    const [qqq, setQQQ] = useState(2);
    //declare function that you want to access
    function funcA(){ /*function to interact with your child components*/}
    function funcB(){ /*function to interact with your child components*/}

    //pure React functional components here
    function Content(){
         //function that you cannot access
         funcC(){ /*.....*/}
         funcD(){/*.......*/}
         //what to render
         return (
           <div> 
               {/* your contents here */} 
           </div>
         )
    }
    //return accessible contents and functions in a JSON
    return {
        content: Content, //function for rendering content
        ExposeA: funcA,   //return as a closure
        ExposeB: funcB,   //return as a closure
    }
}
```

Below is an example of how you would render the child contents within the parent

```
function Parent(){
    let chi = Child();
    let ChildContent = chi.Content;
    //calling your exposed functions
    //these function can interacts with the states that affects child components
    chi.ExposeA();  
    chi.ExposeB();
    //render your child component
    return (<div>
        <div> {/* parent stuff here */</div>
        <div> {/* parent stuff here */</div>
        <ChildContent {/*Define your props here */} />
    </div>)
}
```