# React: Closing Modal in Child Component from Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a modal in a child component that handles a delete function in the parent component. The child is holding the state of the modal (open or closed) as this seems the most logical place for it.

**Parent**

```
 removeItem() {
   console.log('clicked');
  };

 ...

 <DeleteButton deleterecord={()=>this.removeItem(data.row._original._id)}/>
```

**Child**

```
close() {
  this.setState({ showModal: false })
};

open() {
  this.setState({ showModal: true })
};


render() {

 return(
  <div>
    <Button
    bsStyle="primary"
    bsSize="small"
    onClick={this.open.bind(this)}
  >
    Delete
  </Button>

  <Modal
    show={this.state.showModal}
    onHide={this.close.bind(this)}
    bsSize="small"
    >
   ...
```

How should I close the modal from the parent after the removeItem code has run.

Comment: You could call a function in child component from parent that essentially updates the state of the child component. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235420/call-child-method-from-parent-in-react/40235756#40235756

Comment: Edited my solution to use a reference to call the child close function. Check if it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a ref to call the child close function?

**Parent**

```
    removeItem() {
       console.log('clicked');
       this.child.close();
    }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <ChildWithModal ref={(ref) => { this.child = ref; }} />
         </div>
      );
   }
```

**Child**

```
...

close() {
   this.setState({ showModal: false })
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the <DeleteButton> component is in the parent too. I will amend my question to include some of the child code

Comment: Thanks for this what should "this.child" actually be? The name of the child component?

Comment: "child" is the name of the ref. You can assign whatever name you please =). Try to use something that will be easier to identify the component with. Think of it as an alias for the child component.

Comment: Great thanks. That's what I thought, but it doesn't close the modal. :-(

Comment: If I console log "this.child" from the removeItem function I can see the child and it's state, but I can't see the close(). This close() is not within the render of the child though. Is that the issue?

Comment: Not sure why the function isn't showing. Maybe you need to bind the close function in the child constructor?. It should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent

Comment: OK thanks that works and I can see the close function now from the parent, but when I call it there is still no effect.

Comment: OK so it does call the close function from the parent and even changes the state, but it doesn't close the modal. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem and can't make out what's going on here, there's not enough code to understand the solution.