# How access child state from parent component on click event in parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Problem: I am unable to access child state from parent component.

My approach: I can access child state from the parent if I create the state in the parent.

Question: is there any other way if I don't want to create a state in parent component and just get the data from children and make an API call?

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  handleOnClick() {
    client.POST('/post/name',childStateName);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child />
      <button onClick={this.handleOnClick}> save </button>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: 'srk'};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {this.state.name}
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you really should use a single component here. A parent should not need to access the state of its children. A component should be self-contained.

Comment: i have other functionality in child component, i just gave a part of my component since its too big

Comment: is it possible to move both `handleOnClick` and the button from the parent component into the child component?

Comment: i can but i need to make lot of changes , that why i wanted to get the child state @margaretkru

Comment: Then I think this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40235756/6053299) could help you.