# getElementById in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null, getelementbyid

Getting this error at the moment:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

I call this in my render function below:

```
<input type="submit" className="nameInput" id="name" value="cp-dev1" onClick={this.writeData}/>
```

I also have tried calling it in here

```
componentWillMount: function(){
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
      },
```

How can I get the id of an input text field and read that value and ensure it is not null?

I think the DOM is loading after I try to read the element hence why it is null

Comment: 1. try `componentDidMount`, 2. if the input is part of your React component, use refs, e.g. `<input ref="name" />` and `var name = this.refs.name`, 3. Your example input has `id="cp-dev1"` but you try to get element with `id="name"` which doesn't exist in the code you have posted. Does it exist anywhere in your app?

Comment: how do I pass the value from componentDidMount into another function then? I.e. the var name how can I pass that into another function?

Comment: Ive got it partially working but componentDidMount completes it on load but I would rather submit it once I have typed in the values and clicked

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to have your function in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle since this is the function that is called when the DOM has loaded.

Make use of `refs` to access the DOM element

```
<input type="submit" className="nameInput" id="name" value="cp-dev1" onClick={this.writeData} ref = "cpDev1"/>

  componentDidMount: function(){
    var name = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.cpDev1).value;
    this.someOtherFunction(name);
  }
```

See this answer for more info on **[How to access the dom element in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele/38093981#38093981)**

Comment: It is said that string based refs are likely to be deprecated in the near future, superseded by the callback based syntax: `ref={input => this.input = input}`

Comment: when I do this it submits them as empty strings?

Comment: can you please elaborate. it doesn't print name when you console.log() or what

Comment: ok my bad, yours is working but instead of doing it on mount/on load I would rather do it on click? can I just name the function something different to componentDidMount?

Comment: componentDidMount  is a react lifecycle function and is automatically called. In order to do it on click you can name the function something else and the call it as `onClick={this.handleClick}`

Comment: In React documentation page it says that "... use findDOMNode(), but it is discouraged.". Be aware of it. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: This is legacy now!

Comment: findDOMNode  is Deprecated - https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode or https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/findDOMNode

Answer (score 4):

You may have to perform a diff and put `document.getElementById('name')` code inside a condition, in case your component is something like this:

```
// using the new hooks API
function Comp(props) {
  const { isLoading, data } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    }
  }, [data]) // this diff is necessary

  if (isLoading) return <div>isLoading</div>
  return (
    <div id='name'>Comp</div>
  );
}
```

If diff is not performed then, you will get `null`.

Comment: Strange, is there a document about this?

Comment: When the prop "isLoading" is true would mean that the data is not available to the component and the element with id "name" does not exist in the DOM. On success of API call only, after the "isLoading" state is set to `false` would that element be rendered to the DOM.

Answer (score -2):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("satoshi");
  const handleClick = () => {
    setName(document.getElementById("name").value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input id="name" />
      <h2> {name} </h2>
      <button onClick={handleClick} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please always give some description, related to the code you are posting so that any future reader know what exactly happening.

Comment: Add explanation to your answer, so others can understand what exactly you are doing to resolve the issue.