# How to display React-Bootstrap's NavDropdown on Hover

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010814/how-can-i-make-react-bootstraps-dropdown-open-on-mouse-hover), whose top answers no longer work. By default, the NavDropdown only appears when clicked on, however I need this dropdown to display on hover. I struggled loading 'React-Bootstrap' into stackoverflow to create a reproducible example, however here is a basic `Navbar` using `react-bootstrap`, that features my attempt to display the dropdown on hover:

```
const [isStatsOpen, setIsStatsOpen] = useState(true);

<Navbar>
    <Navbar.Brand>
        <Link to='/'>
            <img alt='company logo' src={My Logo} />
        </Link>
    </Navbar.Brand>

    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='basic-navbar-nav' />

    <Navbar.Collapse id='basic-navbar-nav'>
        <Nav className='mr-auto'>
            <NavDropdown title='Statistics'
                onMouseEnter={() => setIsStatsOpen(true)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setIsStatsOpen(false)}
                open={isStatsOpen}
            >
                <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to='/stats/'> Stats 1</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to='/stats2/'>Stats 2</NavDropdown.Item>

            </NavDropdown>

        </Nav>

        <Nav className='ml-auto'>
            <DivisionSelect />
            <AppSelect />
        </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse >
</Navbar >
```

From the linked post above, there were 2 responses with 10+ votes, however neither of these solutions work. As it pointed out in one of the comments: `This doesn't work in newer versions, the dropdown isn't rendered until it's first click. You'd need to trigger the onclick before you could control via css`.

After inspecting the page, I can confirm that this person is correct - there is no menu for which to display until after the NavDropdown has been clicked upon. Once clicked, the menu is there, and then the solutions from this other post do work. Given this as the case, how can I resolve this issue? Is it possible for my react component to automatically "click" the Navdropdowns on load, that way the menus will appear on hover?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you? Old good vanilla javascript.
I added an id at `NavDropdown` and called the old, classic `document.getElementById` method and then triggered the `click` event.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById("test").click();
  }, []);


          <NavDropdown
            id="test"
            title="Statistics"
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-demo-z36c5

Comment: This looks great, and your codesandbox works, however it seems in my application that the useEffect is triggering before the `DOM` has loaded, as I get an error that `document.getElementById("test")` returns null, and I console logged the `document` to see that the DOM hasn't loaded.

Comment: It seems the issue of the DOM having not loaded [is not new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256673/getelementbyid-in-react)

Comment: Hacky and dirty solution but if you included it in a setTimeout of eg 1 second?

Comment: or then, the other solution would be a custom hook to check that component is mount, as I saw some examples at github

Answer (score 0):

In [this link to the earlier version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010814/how-can-i-make-react-bootstraps-dropdown-open-on-mouse-hover), the highly voted answer that starts with `export class Nav extends React.Component {` does work, so long as the `open` prop is updated to `show`.