# Get number from the input text and then increment when the button is clicked ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, increment

I am attempting to make a button increment an input text value.

The button increments or decrements the value. (`value = '+' OR '-'`)
(See picture below)

To get the value of this `input text` and then when use the value what we just get and `+1`

I require a full example of this using reactjs please.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make your input Element to be a controlled one and when you click on buttons you only need to update the state based on which button was clicked

You can read this answer on **[controlled vs uncontrolled Inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471370/reactjs-should-you-have-controlled-or-uncontrolled-inputs/44471458#44471458)**

**Sample Snippet**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 state = {
    count: 0
 }
 
 updateValue = (val) => {
     this.setState(prevState => ({count: prevState.count + val}));
 }
 render() {
    return  <div>
        <input type="number" value={this.state.count} />
        <input type="button" onClick={this.updateValue.bind(this, -1)} value="Decrement"/>
        <input type="button" onClick={this.updateValue.bind(this, 1)} value="Increment"/>
     </div>
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```