# How to get data from multiple inputs and put it to the localStorage? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Register extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    }

    submit(event) {
    let username = document.getElementById('username');
    let usernameValue = username.value;
    localStorage.setItem('username', usernameValue);
    }
    render(){
          return(
            <div className="register-block">
                <h4>Register</h4>
                <div className="register-block">
                    <InputGroup>
                        <Input id="username" placeholder="username" />
                        <Input id="password" placeholder="password" />
                        <Input id="tel" placeholder="tel number" />
                    </InputGroup>
                </div>
                <Button color="primary" onClick ={this.submit}>Register</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

//At this point, I can put data only from input id="username". How can I get data from others inputs and store it in localStorage? Its educational project

Comment: Do you have to add everything to same localStorage entry? or you can have individual entries for each input?

Comment: why cant you use redux, which is best for such purposes.

Comment: This is registration form. And there are 3 inputs: username, password, and tel number. I have to put value from this inputs to the localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
let phone = document.getElementById('tel').value;

let data = [];
data['username'] = username;
data['password '] = password;
data['phone '] = phone;

localStorage.setItem('userdata', JSON.stringify(data));

// To retrieve data try this
data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userdata'));
```

Comment: I'm using something similar to this in a sample app, but the values are replaced at every new entry, do you have an idea what I could do to have a list/array of data stored (NOTE: I'm storing the data in an object and passed into an array).

Comment: The only way to escape replacing object is merging new object state with the old one. It means before seting new state of object you need to retrieve the old object from localStorage and update properties that were changed and save it back to the localStorage...

Comment: You’re right, I solved the problem this way yesterday, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First of all directly interacting with the DOM node in react is not a good idea. Secondly, You can make all your Inputs to be controlled and push the data in `localStorage` on submit like

```
class Register extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
        this.state={
           username: '',
           password: '',
           tel: ''
        }
    }

    handleChange = (key, val) => {
      this.setState({[key]: val})
    }

    submit(event) {

      localStorage.setItem('registerData', JSON.stringify(this.state));
    }
    render(){
          return(
            <div className="register-block">
                <h4>Register</h4>
                <div className="register-block">
                    <InputGroup>
                        <Input id="username" placeholder="username" onChange={(val) => this.handleChange('username', val)} />
                        <Input id="password" placeholder="password" onChange={(val) => this.handleChange('password', val)}/>
                        <Input id="tel" placeholder="tel number" onChange={(val) => this.handleChange('tel', val)} />
                    </InputGroup>
                </div>
                <Button color="primary" onClick ={this.submit}>Register</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Assuming your `Input` is a custom component, you must also look into [`How to pass data from child to parent component`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs/38397755#38397755). Also check [`Controlled Vs UnControlled Components in React`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471370/reactjs-controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs/44471458#44471458)

Comment: I'm using something similar to this in a sample app, but the values are replaced at every new entry, do you have an idea what I could do to have a list/array of data stored (NOTE: I'm storing the data in an object and passed into an array).