# Why does this uncontrolled component work so flawlessly without using State

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I read the ReactJS documentation it recommends using state to create controlled components.  However, the below uncontrolled code is much cleaner and works flawlessly.  I can understand why the parent component should use state, but the below code is so clean that I don't understand why controlled components are recommended.  The "MyModule" prefix is optional and I don't even have to include that.

```
module MyModule {
   export let userName: string = "";

   interface iProps {
      userName?: string;
   }

   export class Build extends React.Component<iProps, {}> {
      constructor(props: iProps) {
         super(props);

         if (props.userName) {
            MyModule.userName = props.userName;
         }
      }

      handleChange(event) {
         MyModule.userName = event.target.value;
      }

      render() {
         return (<input type="text" defaultValue={MyModule.userName} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} /> );
      }
   } //end class.
} //end module.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlled vs uncontrolled components ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471370/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components-reactjs)

Comment: it won't work if you have multiple instances of `Build` component in your app, because each instance will modify the same `userName` variable

Comment: @OzzyWalsh - The accepted answer on the other post does not really apply to this code because this code is using a module level variable so it's value is available throughout the component.

Comment: @OlivierBoissé - All of my components use the same "Build" class and work perfectly because they are encapsulated with different typescript module names.

Comment: hum ,do you have multiple instances `Build` component on the same page ? I don't see the relation with having different module names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because the value that `handleChange(event)` is updating is stored outside the component class.

So basically it works when you have only one instance of `Build` component in your entire application. When you have multiple instances of the same component you probably want to make sure that each instance has its own value for `userName`. You could create multiple variables and associate each one somehow with each component instance, but using component state,  or application-wide state store like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) are better ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The inputs will display the right value because they are uncontrolled. But all the 
 js instances on the same page will have the same username.
Also you will loose the "reactive" part of javascript.
E.G. If you add a label to the input which would display username from input box it won't update on change.