# setState not applying changes in React function component

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to do a Pomodoro Clock timer, which is basically two timers that alternate between.
Thats all the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Challenge20() {
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState('');
    let minutes = 0;
    let seconds = 0;
    const [workRest, setWorkRest] = useState('work');


function startTimer() {
    document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'none';
    minutes = document.getElementById('work').value - 1;
    seconds = 59;
    setInterval(reduceSeconds, 1000);
};

function reduceSeconds() {
    
    if (seconds < 10) {
        setTimer(minutes + ':' + '0' + seconds);
    }
    else {
        setTimer(minutes + ':' + seconds);
    }

    seconds -= 1;

    if (seconds < 1 && minutes > 0) {
        seconds = 59;
        minutes -= 1;
    }
    else if (seconds == 0  && minutes == 0){
        setWorkRest(workRest == 'work' ? 'rest' : 'work');
        minutes = document.getElementById(workRest == 'work' ? 'work' : 'rest').value;
    }
};

return (
    <>  
        <label>Work Minutes:</label>
        <input id='work' type='number' max='60'/>
        <br/>
        <label>Rest Minutes:</label>
        <input id='rest' type='number' max='60'/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <span id='timer'>{workRest} -&gt; {timer}</span>
        <button id='start' onClick={() => startTimer()}>Start!</button>
    </>
);
};

export default Challenge20;
```

The problem is in this part:

> ```
> else if (seconds == 0  && minutes == 0){
>             setWorkRest(workRest == 'work' ? 'rest' : 'work');
>             minutes = document.getElementById(workRest == 'work' ? 'work' : 'rest').value;
>         }
> ```

The `setState` is not changing from `'work'` to `'rest'`, also tried to call a function to change the state, clearing interval and 2 separated `if`, nothing worked, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use DOM manipulation (`document.getElementById`) ? Why not just have the `value={stateVariable}` on your input fields? Maybe read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471370/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components-in-react this answer and refactor a bit?

Comment: Im using `document.getElementById` because idk another way to change `minutes` from one input value to other one without it

Comment: Why not just make it a state variable?

Comment: I can, but how can this solve my problem?

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood the problem, see if the answer I've added now makes sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> useState is not work inside the condition. For ex: you are set the state value in the if condition. State value not updated in condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve? The problem is that the timer keeps going. On the next iteration, it sets `workRest` back to its previous value. To solve this, I used `clearInterval` to stop iterating, and decremented seconds to display 00:00 on the timer. As such, I had to assign the interval creation to a variable we can pass into `clearInterval`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Challenge20() {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState("");
  let minutes = 0;
  let seconds = 0;
  const [workRest, setWorkRest] = useState("work");
  let interval;
  function startTimer() {
    document.getElementById("start").style.display = "none";
    minutes = document.getElementById("work").value - 1;
    seconds = 59;
    interval = setInterval(reduceSeconds, 1);
  }

  function reduceSeconds() {
    if (seconds < 10) {
      setTimer(minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds);
    } else {
      setTimer(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    }

    seconds -= 1;

    if (seconds < 1 && minutes > 0) {
      seconds = 59;
      minutes -= 1;
    } else if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0) {
      console.log();
      setWorkRest(workRest == "work" ? "rest" : "work");
      minutes = document.getElementById(workRest == "work" ? "work" : "rest")
        .value;
      clearInterval(interval);
      seconds -= 1;
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label>Work Minutes:</label>
      <input id="work" type="number" max="60" />
      <br />
      <label>Rest Minutes:</label>
      <input id="rest" type="number" max="60" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <span id="timer">
        {workRest} -&gt; {timer}
      </span>
      <button id="start" onClick={() => startTimer()}>
        Start!
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```