# React equivalent of getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get this `var li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');` to work in React however it is returning null as I guess the dom hasn't fully loaded. so Im looking for the reacty way to do this or a way to not get it to run until the dom has loaded

Comment: Unfortunately React doesn't provide an method to access all the elements by a Tag name as yet(v15.5.4) . 

However keeping this answer as a reference: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/in-react-js-is-there-any-function-similar-like-document-getelementbyid-in-javascript

What you can do is declare a Ref array and then loop over it

Answer (score 3):

You need to run your code on [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). You also need to get `ul` first.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
        let li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
        console.log(li); // you should have an array with list items inside an specific unordered list
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li>item1</li>
                <li>item2</li>
                <li>item3</li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

I would recommend taking a look at [querySelector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) and [querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) since they might be useful.