# Access value entered in input box in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I need to create a menu in Reactjs and call an API using redux to display the data. Now I want to create a search box in the menu to display a particular category. I have tried using refs but it doesn't work. And I guess it is deprecated.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = { datas: []}//props.menu_items 
}

componentWillMount() {
 this.setState({
  datas : require('./sample2')
 });
}

render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <h2>Menu Dashboard</h2>
    <Buttons />
    <div style={{ border:'1px solid 
  #E7E7E7',marginTop:'3%',width:'90%',marginLeft:'5%'}}>
     <Filters />
     <DisplayTable datas={this.state.datas}/>
    </div>
  </div>
   )
  }
  }
  class Buttons extends Component {
   constructor(props){
   super(props);
   // this.state = {searchInput: ''};
   this.search = this.search.bind(this);
  }
  search(event){
   if (event.keyCode === 13) {  
   // this.setState({searchInput: event.target.value});
   console.log(this.refs.searchInput.value);
   event.preventDefault();
   }
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
     <button className="button1">Categories</button>
     <button className="button2">Add Ons</button>
     <FormControl type="text" placeholder="search items"  ref="searchInput"  
     className="search " onKeyDown={this.search} />
     </div>
    )
   }
  }
```

---

How should I access the value entered in the search box so that I can display the data according to it? Also, I want to call the search function by pressing enter. I have tried the above code for both.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ref `searchInput` is the reference of `FormControl` component, not of the input component. The `FormControl` is not storing the value of input in its reference.

Instead, pass an `onChange` handler to the `FormControl` component and store the value of input in your state like this:

```
onChange = e => {
  this.setState({ value: e.target.value })
}
```

and modify your `search` function to this:

```
  search = e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      console.log('this.state.value..', this.state.value)
    }
  }
```

Render your `FormControl` like this:

```
<FormControl value={this.state.value} type="text" placeholder="search items" 
                   className="search " onChange={this.onChange} onKeyDown={this.search} />
```

Comment: Thanks , it  works fine but whenever I press enter after typing in a word it shows --Cannot read property 'state' of null.
search
G:\menu-services\menu\src\components\map\presentational\map.js:110
  107 | }  
  108 | search(e) {  
  109 |   if (e.keyCode === 13) {  
> 110 |     console.log(this.state.searchString);  
  111 |   }  
  112 | }  
  113 | render() {

Comment: I don't think there should be any error as per above code. Try binding ` this.search = this.search.bind(this)` in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code, I used name for search item you can replace with it searchInput.For redux action search you need to create a search action within that you can call the api and can store that data into props.

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {SearchItems} from "../actions/SearchAction";

/**
 * Search Item Class
 */
class Search extends React.Component {
  /**
   * Constructor
   * @param props
   */
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: ""
    }
  }

  /**
   * Set the search text data into the state object
   * @param event
   */
  searchByText = (event) => {
    this.state[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.props.SearchItems(this.state);
  }

  /**
   * Render the Search filter options.
   * @returns {XML}
   */
  render() {
    return (
       <div className="col-md-8 pull-left">
              <div className="form-group form-control-by-1">
                <input type="text" className="form-control-search search-input-box" id="name" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={(e) => this.searchByText(e)} placeholder="Search "/>
              </div>
            </div>
    );
  }
}

/**
 * Call the Search action function with search data.
 * @param dispatch
 * @returns {{SearchItems: (function(*=))}}
 */
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    SearchItems: (inputData) => {
      dispatch(SearchItems(inputData));
    }
  };
};


/**
 * attach  both Reducer and Action into the Search component.
 */
export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(Search);
```

Comment: Now wherever I want to display this search box , I call this.props.Search?I am learning redux so i do not know much

Comment: No, The search function will handle it, whenever you search something it will automatically trigger that function

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `FormControl` assigns a `ref` to child `input` element, when you pass with the prop name `inputRef`.Also React docs suggest on using the callback approch for refs over the string refs.

See this answer for more info:

[In React .js: is there any function similar like document.getElementById() in javascript ? how to select certain object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/in-react-js-is-there-any-function-similar-like-document-getelementbyid-in-ja/38093981#38093981)

So you can assign the ref and get the value like

```
class Buttons extends Component {
   constructor(props){
   super(props);
   // this.state = {searchInput: ''};
   this.search = this.search.bind(this);
  }
  search(event){
   if (event.keyCode === 13) {  
   console.log(this.searchInput.value);
   event.preventDefault();
   }
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
     <button className="button1">Categories</button>
     <button className="button2">Add Ons</button>
     <FormControl type="text" placeholder="search items"  inputRef={(ref) => {this.searchInput=ref}}  
     className="search " onKeyDown={this.search} />
     </div>
    )
   }
  }
```

Comment: A small mistake. An extra curly bracket is added here: `inputRef={(ref) => this.searchInput=ref}}`