# In react-router v4 , how can I get the "Ref" of the tag <a> created by tag "<Link/>"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In below code:

```
<MyComponent>
  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
</MyComponent>
```

and then , because of the < Link /> ,There  will be create a tag < a >

how can I get the Ref of < a >?

Thanks !

Comment: https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html   try refs.

Comment: see this \https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/in-react-js-is-there-any-function-similar-like-document-getelementbyid-in-ja/38093981#38093981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the ref attribute.

```
<MyComponent>
  <Link to="/" ref="homeLink">Home</Link>
</MyComponent>
```

If you are attempting to apply something to the **a** element node itself (which I assume you are), you can:

```
var homeLink = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.homeLink);
```

Then you can add classes, change styles, etc. to the homeLink variable as it references the actual DOM node and not the React Link component. Just make sure to do this after MyComponent renders (e.g. the componentDidMount() method in the lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to find this to lock focus in a modal nav bar.

`findDomNode` works, at least for now, but it [may be on track for deprecation](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678#issue-165177220). It turns out that `Link` has a native `innerRef` attribute that you can use in the exact same way you would use `ref` on a normal element. [Check it out here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md#innerref-function).