# Can't add a ref to an object which will be reloaded by setState

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I just wanted to add a ref to  object because I have to clear its value.
I wrote like :

```
this.code = (
    <div className="form-group">
          <label className="form-label" htmlFor="target">Target</label>
          <input className="input" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} ref="textbox" id="target" type="text" placeholder="Target" />
        </div>
);
this.setState(this.state);
```

And got an error like:

```
Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded
```

All I want to do is simple : If I click a button, the existing form will be cleared, and some other form will come up. To do that, I tried using a `setState` method. Is it a wrong approach?

Comment: from what I know ref need a function as the input. Can you show us the textbox function?

Comment: @HanaAlaydrus, Its not a necessity but a suggested way . Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/in-react-js-is-there-any-function-similar-like-document-getelementbyid-in-ja/38093981#38093981

Comment: this seems like your case https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_refs.htm

Comment: @HanaAlaydrus Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a
>   component that was not created inside a component's `render` method,
>   or you have multiple copies of React loaded

According to the React Docs:

```
This usually means one of two things:

1. You are trying to add a ref to an element that is being created outside of a component's render() function.
2. You have multiple (conflicting) copies of React loaded (eg. due to a misconfigured NPM dependency)
```

You case seems to be the first one, where you are trying to create the document object outside of your render function.

The solution would be to have a function called from the render function that returns a document object

```
renderInput = () => {
    return (
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="form-label" htmlFor="target">Target</label>
          <input className="input" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} ref={(ref) => this.textbox = ref} id="target" type="text" placeholder="Target" />
        </div>
    )
}
render() {
   return (
       <div>
            {this.renderInputForm()}
      </div>
   )
}
```

P.S. React suggests to use callback approach for refs instead of string refs. Check this answer:

[In React .js: is there any function similar like document.getElementById() in javascript ? how to select certain object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/in-react-js-is-there-any-function-similar-like-document-getelementbyid-in-ja/38093981#38093981)

Also in case of [**Invalid Refs**](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html):

> Only a ReactOwner can have refs. This usually means that you're trying
>   to add a ref to a component that doesn't have an owner (that is, was
>   not created inside of another component's render method). Try
>   rendering this component inside of a new top-level component which
>   will hold the ref.