# React array of refs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, refs

i have read in a post on Stackoverflow [question about refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/in-react-js-is-there-any-function-similar-like-document-getelementbyid-in-ja/38093981#38093981)

that we can use something like the following code to assign an array of refs to different inputs like this:

```
<Progressbar completed={25} id="Progress1" ref={(input) => {this.Progress[0] = input }}/>

<Progressbar completed={50} id="Progress2" ref={(input) => {this.Progress[1] = input }}/>

<Progressbar completed={75} id="Progress3" ref={(input) => {this.Progress[2] = input }}/>
```

but when i try it, it returns this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
```

and it doesn't work, am I missing something?

Comment: Have you set a default variable? `Progress = []`.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this with the React.createRef() API?

Comment: How would access this reference list in another function? say you want to refer to index 1, for instance!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create the array in you constructor, like:

```
constructor(){
  super()

  this.Progress = []
}
```

Comment: How would access this reference list in another function? say you want to refer to index 1, for instance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Progress array is not initialized, initialize it in constructor..