# React.js How do I get the id in props with the getElementById method?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

start to learn React.js recently and encounter the following problem: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnDYJ.png)

I want to get the `div` element using `getElementById` but it doesn't work and the console alerts `can not read property 'props' of null`. So how can I get the `div` element? it has troubled me for several hours. 
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dada Jiao-- welcome to StackOverflow.  You may want to review [ask].  Generally it is considered poor practice to include a link to an image of code.  It would be much better to include the code in the question itself, as well as a _explicit_ explanation of what is going wrong.  Beyond that, I would remind you that that sort of direct DOM manipulation is not generally what React is all about-- if you _truly_ need a DOM reference review [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) -- but note that often it is not necessary.

Comment: make use of refs instead of directly accessing the DOM, you can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/in-react-js-is-there-any-function-similar-like-document-getelementbyid-in-ja/38093981#38093981

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea with React is that you don't access the DOM, but work with a virtual DOM.

To achieve what you are trying to accomplish (which is a little unclear since the code is incomplete), you'll want to use a [stateful component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) that stores user input on `this.state`. Check out [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) on React forms.

You'll want to do something like this, where you are tracking user input by storing it on the component:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I tried with your method and it works!

Comment: Great! If you're satisfied with the answer, please mark it as correct and close the issue.