# How to convert a React Element from its Object form back to Tag form when printing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a demo to show off UI elements for a project. I am running into a specific issue whenever I try to assign a React Element to a variable and print.

UPDATE: To clarify the workflow of what I'm doing. For each UI element I want to put on my demo, I create a file which stores the properties I want to populate it with when I render it.

For example: Let’s say I want to show case the `<strong>` tag with something like

`<strong>This is a Strong element</strong>`

There would be a file structured something like:

```
{ name: 'Strong',
   props: { 
      children: <strong>This is a Strong element</strong>
   } 
 }
```

Visually you just see: **This is a Strong element**

Below I want to show what the code looks like.

What I want to print is: `<strong>This is a Strong element</strong>`

But what I see is: `{"type”:”strong”,”key":null,"ref":null,"props":{"children":"This is a Strong element”},”_owner":null,"_store":{}}`

I know that is how React elements are stored and that is what’s actually what’s going on under the hood when I write `<strong>This is a Strong element</strong>`, but how do I go back to printing `<strong>This is a Strong element</strong>` instead of the regular object?

Comment: I guess you want to [read the innerHTML of your component after its rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456644/how-to-get-a-react-components-innerhtml)

Comment: is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/zho51wku/

Comment: @Surely no sorry, I think i've been a bit unclear im going to update and explain what I'm doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my specific problem, I discovered the npm module jsx-to-string which will take the object `<strong> This is Strong </strong>` and spit out "`<strong>` This is Strong `</strong>`"

Answer (score 1):

Could you format it as a string :

```js
var element = {'type':'strong','props':{'children':'This is a Strong element'}};

console.log(`<${element.type}>${element.props.children}</${element.type}>`);
```

Comment: It will not work if element.props.children is an object in itself.