# How to get JSX Element's outerHTML BEFORE calling ReactDOM.render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a Component:

```js
function MyComp(props) {
  return (
    <div class="myJSX">
      Some Content.
      { props.children }
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want to get the outerHTML ***before*** I render it.

More emphasis on ***before***

> Question is about before rendering, answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456644/how-to-get-a-react-components-innerhtml) won't help me.
>
> **By render, I mean calling `ReactDOM.render`**

**Note:** This is in Node.js not purely in-browser. Any node related answer is also very helpful.

No Idea is too bad.

So the outer HTML of:

```
<MyComp>hello</MyComp>
```

should look like:

```
<div class="myJSX">
  Some Content.
  hello
</div>
```

Comment: If I understood the question, `MyComp` is a function (function component), I think you can't get its `outerHTML` before calling it, ie rendering it.

Comment: Or try giving an example output you expect

Comment: Why would you want to know outerHTML?

Comment: @DennisVash By Rendering, I meant calling `ReactDOM.render`

Comment: It is not what rendering means, you should fix your question, and yes, it is possible (if I understood the question), please show an expected output/behavior

Comment: Is it ok now, @DennisVash ?

Comment: **Please show an expected output/behavior**

Comment: Now @DennisVash ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to know value of `children` before you actually render the component

Comment: Are you sure, @user0101, I would basically accept any method that let's me do it, whether it's virtual dom or something else. Anything that gives me what ReactDOM.render would render.

Comment: I don't get the logic behind your question. There might be some other ways to achieve what you are after - just give us hint what it is

Answer (score 2):

"I want to get the outerHTML before I render it." But rendering **is** basically creating a structure that will be converted to html.

With a few assumptions:

- By "before" you mean before rendering on a client
- You want this in your backend ("This is in Node.js").

You could use [`ReactDOMServer.renderToString` method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring)

Something like this

```
const {renderToString} = require('react-dom/server');

const html = renderToString(<MyComp>Hello</MyComp>)
```

Comment: Best answer yet, i'm just going to check this, and accept it.

Comment: That's not [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) like the OP asked, but it really what he might mean in his problem

Comment: @DennisVash It is hard to say what outer html for react component even means. But the result would be exactly what OP has posted as a desired output.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko It is not true, `renderToString` and `outerHTML` don't give the same output, you can check it

Comment: Reread the question plz. OP has posted desired output and renderToString would give exactly that. There is no such thing as outerHTML (or innerHTML, or adjacentHTML) for react components. JSX is not html though `<MyComp>Hello</MyComp>` looks like one.

Comment: Of course there isn't, you get the `outerHTML` from the reference, and the question is "How to get JSX Element's outerHTML ...?", you literally can see my deleted answer