# Send rendered component output to backend

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that renders the answers of a contact form and presents them in the page.
eg:

```
  const Quote = ({fields}) => {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          Business Type: {fields.businesstype.value}
        </div>
        ....
      </>
    )
  }
```

I need to send the rendered data to the php backend in order to send them as an email.

The question: Can I use the same component to get the rendered data (in a variable) and send them to backend (with axios)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set ref to target Component (in this case Quote) and
use it like this:
`ReactDOM.findDOMNode(quoteRef).innerHTML`

to get rendered HTML code of that component

[take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456644/how-to-get-a-react-components-innerhtml)

Comment: Thank you your answer. But isn't dangerous to use innerHTML?

Comment: reading `innerHTML` is perfectly safe; it's setting `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` that can potentially introduce security holes in your React app.

Answer (score 0):

you can add ref to your component and have full access on that like this

```
  const Quote = ({fields}) => {
    const ref = React.useRef()
    return (
  <>
    <div ref={ref}>
      Business Type: {fields.businesstype.value}
    </div>
    ....
  </>
)
}
```