# Any event triggered after React component mounted in DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I try to do `document.querySelector` for an element inside the React component inside `componentDidMount`, it seems like it does not guarantee it (`componentDidMount`) gets called after its on the DOM. The result is it cannot find the element

Is there an event I should used instead if I want to access the DOM? After its attached to the DOM?

As a workaround, I used `setTimeout` is there a better way?

Comment: async/await is also useful.

Comment: use 'ref' instead of querySelector?

Comment: You might wanna have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele/38093981#38093981

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is that in your componentDidMount method set some state change. it makes an update on your component and call render method again with absolute mounted status.

like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({
    isMounted: true
  })
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
  if(nextState.isMounted){
     // do something for your query selecting
  }
}

componentWillUnmount(){
  // do something else if you want
}
```