# For what Ref is used in React native? Please tell what ref is doing here

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here is my code sample please tell me purpose of using ref

```
<Camera
          ref={(cam) => {
           this.Camera = cam;
         }}
          style={styles.preview}
          aspect={camera.constants.Aspect.fill} >
          <Text style={styles.capture} 
          onPress = { this.takePicture.bind(this )}>
          [CAPTURE]
          </Text>

</Camera>
```

Comment: are you asking what are refs for?  https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: use of ref in this specific code

Comment: hard to tell without the surrounding context of this code. somewhere some code is using `this.Camera` (probably) and we need to see this block of code as well to be sure what the purpose is.

Comment: refs are generally used to access the ReactElement, just like `document.getElementById()` in normal javascript See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele/38093981#38093981

Comment: You don't have to if your are not making use of 'this.Camera' anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using the reference:

```
    <Camera
          ref={(cam) => {
           this.Camera = cam;
         }}
          style={styles.preview}
          aspect={camera.constants.Aspect.fill} >
          <Text style={styles.capture} 
          onPress = { this.takePicture.bind(this )}>
          [CAPTURE]
          </Text>

</Camera>

takePicture() {
    this.Camera.capture()
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

`ref` returns a reference to the component. In the above example you are storing reference of the component `Camera` in `this.Camera`( you can name it whatever like `this.xyz` or whatever). Now you can access all the methods of `Camera` component using `this.Camera`. In the above example `capture` is a method of `Camera` component and you can call it like this `this.Camera.capture()`.

You can think of it like this, for easier understanding:

```
Camera = { // your <Camera /> component
    capture: function(){ console.log('CAPTURE')}
}
myCamera = Camera // ref is doing something like this("myCamera" replaces "this.Camera", "Camera" replaces 'cam" )
myCamera.capture() // now you can call methods of Camera Object
```