# ReactJS - How to use 'ref' property for scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, ref

In react "^15.4.1", I want to display middle section of a page after reload. So I am trying to do it using scrollbar but I am getting an error like,

```
main.js:43122 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of null
 at ref (main.js:43122)
 at detachRef (main.js:82172)
 at Object.ReactRef.detachRefs (main.js:82227)
 at Object.receiveComponent (main.js:10145)
 at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (main.js:77618)
```

Importing like, `import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';` and the version is `4.0.1`

In .jsx file,

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.scrollTop(200);
}

handleScrolling = (frame) => {
 if(frame.top === 1) this.setState({ loading: true })
}

scrollTop = (value) => {
  if(this.refs.scrollbar) this.refs.scrollbar.scrollTop(value);
}

<Scrollbars
    ref={(scrollbar) => {scrollbar.scrollTop(200);}}
    style={{ height: '100vh' }} onScrollFrame={this.handleScrolling}>
    ...
```

How can I fix this issue? Actually I am new to ReactJS. Please help me regarding the same.

Comment: can you provide the code for `Scrollbars` component and overall give us some more context in terms of code?

Comment: you are not defining the red correctly, check this answer on how do you do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele/38093981#38093981

Comment: Could you send the full code to the component?

Answer (score 0):

In this part you just need to place your ref.

```
<Scrollbars
  ref={(scrollbar) => { this.scrollbar = scrollbar; }}
```

Then you can use the ref to do your stuff.

```
scrollTop (value) => {
  this.scrollbar.scrollTop(value);
}
```

Comment: Updated the question. Scroll is not happening on reload.

Comment: would be great if you share the code of `ScrollBars`, or create a repro in `codepen`. Until then hard to say what's wrong.

Comment: Actually its a package called `react-custom-scrollbars`, there is no code for that other than what I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Did you try what I pointed out in my answer? If that doesn't work you can try `console.log(this.scrollbar)` to see if `scrollTop` is available in the object.