# How to set scrollTop property of ReactDOM node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, scrolltop, react-dom

Setting the scrollTop property of a React node is not working.

I'm trying to restore the scroll position of a list when navigating to and from the page with the list.

Currently my code is the following:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let prevScrollHeight = Number(localStorage.getItem('listHeight'));

    if (prevScrollHeight >= 0) {
      let listNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.speakersList);
      listNode.scrollTop = prevScrollHeight;
    }
  }
```

The scroll height is successfully being stored in local storage. What's not working is: `listNode.scrollTop = prevScrollHeight`

Does anyone know how I can set the scroll position of a React node?

Comment: Instead of defining the refs as strings, you need to define them using ref callback syntax, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele/38093981#38093981

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant at all to the problem at hand (and the solution posted below).

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue... For future reference if you have the same issue - the solution was to put the function that was setting the scrolltop in `setTimeout`. Seems like it has something to do with the JavaScript event loop, and `setTimeout` puts the function at the back of the queue.

Working code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(this.setScrollTop.bind(this))
}

setScrollTop() {
  let prevScrollHeight = Number(localStorage.getItem('listHeight'));

  if (prevScrollHeight >= 0) {
    let listNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.speakersList);
    listNode.scrollTop = prevScrollHeight;
  }
}
```