# ReactJS - Window.ScrollTo() not working on secondary scroll bar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, scroll

For my ReactJS project I have a simple text list (using `<ul>` and `<li>` tags), which has it's own scroll bar to navigate through the list, but not the whole page. I was able to do this with this css code:

```
    #List-container {
        max-height: 425px;
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

For my project, I need it to automatically scroll down to the bottom of the list. I tried using `window.scrollTo()`but it's not working, which I'm pretty sure is because of the fact that there is a secondary scroll bar.

Does anyone know how I could use `window.ScrollTo()`, or know any alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it should be `window.scrollTo` not `ScrollTo`

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it again and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and I'm getting a scrollbar like it's supposed to.

To get something to automatically scroll to bottom I would do something like:

```
let wHeight = window.innerHeight;
window.scrollY = wHeight;
```

This is the simplest way I can think of to scroll to the bottom of the page. You can replace window with whatever you want to select in the DOM.

To instead scroll to the bottom of your list simply write:

```
let divHeight = document.getElementById('List-container');
window.scrollY = divHeight.offsetHeight;
```

Comment: Is there a more "Reactjs-ly" alternative to .getElementByID? It might just be me, but I feel .getElementByID doesn't really fit with ReactJS

Comment: There is, but I can't say if it's better or worse. getElementById is as close to the DOM as you can get when selecting an element. But with React you have "refs" where you can set for example <div ref="myReactDiv"> and you can later select this with this.refs.myReactDiv. Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't `window.scrollY` just a `read-only` property? How can you modify it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get reference for the `ListContainer` and then set `scrollTop` on it like

```
<ListContainer ref={ref => this.listContainer = ref} />
```

and use it like

```
const container = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.listContainer);
container.scrollTop = "125px"
```

Comment: On the top line what does `this.listContainer` represent?

Comment: Its a ref to the ListContainer component, check this for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele/38093981#38093981

Comment: So if I wanted to I could change `this.listContainer` to what ever name I want - as it's being defined in that line? Am I right?

Comment: @Ben10, you can give whatever name you want.

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions, but it's still not working. Am I setting the const `container` in the wrong part of the reactjs lifecycle or does it not matter?'

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the container, and when do you want to set scrollPosition, also are you getting any error

Comment: I am not getting any error when I start the development server nor in the console. And for the scroll position I want it on button press.

Comment: For the container I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: In that case, you must call the function on button click in which you will set `this.listContainer.scrollTop = '125px'`