# How to access DOM element's attributes and value inside an event handler function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

My render function is

```
<input type="text" id="search" data-id={form.id} value={form.name} placeholder= "Search..." name="id" onKeyUp={this.keyUpFn}"/>
```

and my `keyUpFn` function is

```
keyUpFn(e){
    var textInput = document.getElementById('search');
    value1 = textInput.getAttribute('data-id')
    value2 = e.getAttribute('data-id')
    console.log(value1 )
    console.log(value2 )
}
```

Both console value gives error as `getAttribute` is not defined. How can I solve this in React?

Comment: You can find the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele

Comment: @tarunluthra This is not the answer i'm looking for..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data from the Event [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) object. This is how the code would look

```
keyUpFn(e){
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-id'));
    console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get the data requested from the event (e) in your function by accessing

```
event.currentTarget.dataset.paramater;

keyUpFn(e) {
  e.currentTarget.dataset.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getElementsByClassName (or id, name etc.), querySelectorAll, focus.
First two returns an array of all valid elements.