# Using string literals in ref attributes is deprecated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eslint

I am doing this in react native code, eslint is showing error for line `ref="drawer"`

> [eslint] Using string literals in ref attributes is deprecated.

What is correct way to do this.

```
<DrawerLayoutAndroid
                drawerWidth={300}
                ref="drawer"
                drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
                renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}
            </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to make use of `ref callback pattern` as [**string refs are deprecated.**](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs)

```
<DrawerLayoutAndroid
            drawerWidth={300}
            ref={(ref) => this.drawer = ref}
            drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
            renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}
        </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
```

`(ref) => this.drawer = ref` is an arrow function syntax, you can simplify it similar to

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props); 
   this.setRef = this.setRef.bind(this);
}
setRef(ref) {
   this.setRef = ref;
}

...
ref={this.setRef}
```

Check this answer for more info

[How to access a DOM element in React? What is the equilvalent of document.getElementById() in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele/38093981#38093981)

Comment: I am new to js, can you explain this syntax a little.

Comment: @Khemraj, this is an arrow function syntax, check the update

Answer (score -3):

you can wrap them with curly braces to indicate it's valid JS syntax

```
<DrawerLayoutAndroid
            drawerWidth={300}
            ref={'DRAWER'}
            drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
            renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}
        </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
```

Comment: Even if you add curly braces es-lint errors will show the same

Comment: @TinoJoseThannippara: I'm pretty sure they wont but it could be due to your code editor taking some time for refreshing. You can try to reopen the page

Comment: question is asking the correct way to solve the error eslint is showing, and not how to workaround the eslint rule