# Get rendered react component to send back to server

Tags: reactjs

I have several react components from which i want to get a component  as html string to send to server .
lets say the component i want to send is `<ReportComponent />`
how it can be done.
I tried

`onRouteChanged = () => {
    console.log(<ReportComponent />);
  };`

but this is not giving me as html.

**Scenario is this**

On click of a send button the currently viewing component on client machine should be send to the server to save as a report .

Comment: Could you please explain a little more of your use case? I feel like there is something conceptually wrong here.

Comment: @Victor i have updated the scenario

Comment: hm ok so basically you want to tell the server where the user is on the page?

Comment: @Victor not exactly . this page is basically a report. i want to save that report to db

Comment: why not send a JSON with the data instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could use plain `document.querySelector` and `innerHTML` property.

In `ReportComponent` add a wrapping `div` to render method and give it an id:

```
<div id="reportComponent">...important stuff that gets rendered...</div>
```

After `ReportComponent` is already rendered and in the DOM, you can do

```
const reportComponentHTML = document.querySelector("#reportComponent").innerHTML;
//send it to server or log it to console
console.log(reportComponentHTML)
```

Comment: this wont give me styles  @Kristupas

Comment: You are asking for html specifically. However, your approach might be incorrect if you're trying so save some kind of report. Since you own html and css of report component, it would be correct to send only the data of the report to server and attach html and css on the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `renderToString()` method

You need to use `import {renderToString} from react-dom/server`

Then log the component like

```
renderToString(<MyAwesomeComponent/>)
```

Make sure you pass the required props.

Comment: i tried this but getting following error
`Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(InterpReport)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(InterpReport)".`

Comment: Are you using redux?

Comment: The component is not getting t he required props from the store. So as the error message says try passing the sore as a props inside the <Provider> or the connect() method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your problem is to get the complete HTML of rendered element.
You have to ways to deal with either assign `ID attribute` or use `refs attribute` on the components and while calling `onRouteChanged` either fetch your component using `getElementById` or using refs in react.

For refs example you can refer 
[How to access a DOM element in React? What is the equilvalent of document.getElementById() in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele)

NOTE : refs might be depreciated in future release of react