# how to get input field value on button click in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could you please tell me how to get input field value on button click in react , I am using react hooks .I want to get `first name` and `lastname` value on button click. I already pass `name` attribute in my function component.

Here is my [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2vyn2k)

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export default function InputField({name,label}) {
  const [state, setState] = useState('')
  return (
    <div>
     <label>{label}</label>
      <input type="text" 
      value={state} 
      name={name}
      onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)} />

      {state}
    </div>
  );

}
```

Comment: Hi user944513, have you had any luck integrating a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Use `<form>` tag with `useRef` hook

Wrap your `<InputField>` tags with an html `<form>` tag and put a react `ref` on the later. Like this:

```
import React, { Component, useRef } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

import InputField from './inputfield'

import './style.css'

function App () {
  const nameForm = useRef(null)

  const handleClickEvent = () => {
     const form = nameForm.current
     alert(`${form['firstname'].value} ${form['lastname'].value}`)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form ref={nameForm}>
       <InputField label={'first name'} name={'firstname'}/>
       <InputField label={'last name'} name={'lastname'}/>
      </form>
      <button onClick={handleClickEvent}>gett value</button>
    </div>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

**Working example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-shtnxj

Answer (score 6):

**The Easiest Way For Me is `useRef`**

With `useRef` it's pretty simple. Just add `ref` name and then submit.

```js
const email = useRef(null);

function submitForm(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 
 console.log(email.current.value);
}

return (
 <div>
  <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
   <input type="text" ref={email} />
   <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
 </div>
)
```

Comment: But how can I use one ref for multiple fields?

Comment: You can use ref in multiple fields too. for example: `<input type="password" ref={password} />`. or you can get the values from `event.target.password.value` without using `useRef`. I would suggest using external libraries like `react-hooks-form`, `formik` for faster production.

Comment: Actually, I am using `react-hooks-form` and the challenge is the nested form

Answer (score 4):

You could always lift up the state in parent component.
[codeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-butterfly-0xugf)

Parent Component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ChildComponent from "./Child";

const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [first_name, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [last_name, setLastName] = useState("");
  const handleFirstNameChange = ({ target }) => {
    setFirstName(target.value);
  };
  const handleLastNameChange = ({ target }) => {
    setLastName(target.value);
  };
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(first_name);
    console.log(last_name);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChildComponent
        label="first name"
        onChange={handleFirstNameChange}
        value={first_name}
      />
      <ChildComponent
        label="last name"
        onChange={handleLastNameChange}
        value={last_name}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Child Component

```
import React from "react";

const ChildComponent = ({ label, onChange, value, name }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <input type="text" value={value} name={name} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

You could always combine onChange handler for first name and last name.

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is to move the state from InputField component into index:

```
    const [F_name, setF_name] = useState('')
    const [L_name, setL_name] = useState('')
```

now you should pass state value and event handler to InputField to change the state when input is changed:

```
 <InputField label={'first name'} name={'firstname'} value={F_name} changed={(name) => setF_name(name)}/>
```

In Your InputField field: edit it to be like:

```
   <input type="text" 
      value={value} 
      name={name}
      onChange={(e) => changed(e.target.value)} />
```

[See Working Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ka5s74?file=inputfield.js)

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
    const ViewDetail = () => {
      const textFirstName = useRef(null)   
      const onChange = e => {
        console.log(textFirstName.current.state.value) 
      } 
    
    return <Input maxLength={30} ref={textFirstName} placeholder="Nombre" onChange=onChange} />
  }
```

Comment: console.log(textFirstName.current.value) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I can think of these approaches -

- You can pull the state up to the parent component.

App.js

```
const [user, setUser] = useState('');

return (
 <Inputfield setValue={setUser} value={user} />
);
```

InputField.js

```
<input value={props.value}  onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
```

---

- You can use `ref` to access indiviual element value.

---

- If you have data distributed across multiple components you can also make use of `Context` API

---

Hope this helps!

Do let me know if you need more info on any of the option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should do the react hooks work on your index and pass the value and the onChange function to your InputField component.

```
//index page
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import InputField from './inputfield';
import './style.css';

function App() {
  const [firstname, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastname, setLastName] = useState('');
  const handleClickEvent = ()=>{
    setFirstName('Will');
    setLastName('smith');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <InputField
        label={'first name'}
        name={'firstname'}
        value={firstname}
        onChange={setFirstName}
      />
      <InputField
        label={'last name'}
        name={'lastname'}
        value={lastname}
        onChange={setLastName}
      />
      <button 
        onClick={handleClickEvent}

      >Get value</button>
    </div>
  );

}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```
// input field

import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export default function InputField({name,label, value, onChange}) {
  return (
    <div>
     <label>{label}</label>
      <input type="text" 
      value={value} 
      name={name}
      onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} />

      {value}
    </div>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While keeping the majority of your structure the same, I think the simplest and most React solution is to use `forwardRef()` which in a nut-shell let's us communicate between then parent-component and child-components.

See working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-roentgen-uzrrn).

### App.js

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import InputField from "./InputField";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const handleClickEvent = () => {
    if (firstName.current && lastName.current) {
      console.log(`firstName: ${firstName.current.value}`);
      console.log(`lastName: ${lastName.current.value}`);
    }
  };

  const firstName = useRef(null);
  const lastName = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <InputField ref={firstName} label={"first name"} name={"firstname"} />
      <InputField ref={lastName} label={"last name"} name={"lastname"} />
      <button onClick={handleClickEvent}>Get value</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### InputField.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const InputField = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{props.label}</label>
      <input
        ref={ref}
        type="text"
        value={state}
        name={props.name}
        onChange={e => setState(e.target.value)}
      />

      {state}
    </div>
  );
});

export default InputField;
```

Notice that with this structure, you are not required to pass in any state updating function as `props` to the `InputField` component. The value that you enter into each input will be strictly maintained by the individual component. It is independent from the `Parent`, and therefore makes it much more reusable.

The refs we created allow us to tap into specific elements of the `InputField` so we extract the desired values. In this case, we can get first-name and last-name through the `handleClickEvent` function.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this doing the following:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export default function InputField({name,label}) {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');
  const handleChange = e => {
    setState(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
     <label>{label}</label>
      <input
        type="text" 
        value={state} 
        name={name}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      {state}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hopes this helps.

Answer (score -1):

well one simple(but not necessarily recommended) way is to provide an id or a ref like this in index.js

```
<InputField label={'first name'} name={'firstname'} id={"ip1"}/>
<InputField label={'last name'} name={'lastname'} id={"ip2"}/>
```

and in your inputfield.js pass the id props to the input fields like this

```
<input type="text" 
      value={state} 
      name={name}
      onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)} 
      id= {id}/>
```

Now you can call them in the onClick of the button like this in index.js

```
const handleClickEvent = ()=>{
  alert(document.getElementById("ip1").value);
  }
```

The second, more preferable way is to set the state variable in index.js

```
function App() {
  const [stateIp1, setStateIp1] = useState('');
  const [stateIp2, setStateIp2] = useState('');
  const handleClickEvent = ()=>{
  alert(stateIp1);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <InputField label={'first name'} state={stateIp1} setState={setStateIp1} name={'firstname'} id={"ip1"}/>
        <InputField label={'last name'}state={stateIp2} setState={setStateIp2} name={'lastname'} id={"ip2"}/>
        <button 
          onClick={handleClickEvent}

        >Get value</button>
    </div>
  );

}
```

Now your inputfield.js becomes

```
export default function InputField({name,label,id,setState,state}) {

  return (
    <div>
     <label>{label}</label>
      <input type="text" 
      value={state} 
      name={name}
      onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)} id= {id}/>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: you should avoid using `document` in react. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele/38093981#38093981

Comment: @KareemDabbeet Yes, I know  which is why I said "simple(but not necessarily recommended) way" and also I've edited the answer with the second option....I accidentaly posted only the first part of my answer