# How can I get the href id from a react route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the id of a route from a react.js project like this: `page1#view-all`

I tried with the native JavaScript `document` and `window` but unfortunely I can't get it that way because of the SSR.

Is there any alternative to the functions mentioned above? How can I get the router link with the href id? `page1#view-all`

Thanks

FYI, the errors I'm getting when using `document` or `window` I'm getting that any of these isn't defined.

Here's a code snippet:

```
<Link
                to="/page1#view-all"
                className={`subItem-anchor
                ${
                  route && route.split("/")[route.split("/").length - 1] === "all-projects"
                    ? "subnavitemHighlightd"
                    : ""
                }`}
              >
```

`route` is actually the other routes such as `page1/another-sub-page` but I can't get `page1#view-all`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a DOM element in React? What is the equilvalent of document.getElementById() in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele)

Comment: @mrdeadsven Not really, I'm looking for a react way.

Answer (score 1):

Use `react-router-dom`

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
```

and access like this

```
  let location = useLocation()
  console.log(location);
```

The `useLocation` hook returns the location object which contains the `pathname`, `search`, `hash`, `key` and the state properties of the current location.

Sample code to access

```
function App(){

let location = useLocation()
return(
<h3>Access from useLocation</h3>
)}
```

or if it's class based component then access like this without importing anything

```
let urlData = this.props.location;
console.log(urlData);
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `Attempted import error: 'useLocation' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'`

Comment: It's a class based component and `this.props.location` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix, what I did:

```
render() {
  { ssr } = this.props

  if (ssr) return
  const urlId = window.location.toString().split("#")[1]

  return(
    <div>URL ID: {urlId}</div>
  )
}
```