# React wait for parent component to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a bug in my React code where a component needs to locate an element on the page, but that element is not yet rendered.

The render method that handles calling both these components looks like this:

```
render() {
    const generatedId = "myComponent123"
    return (
        <ParentComponent generatedId={generatedId}>
           <ChildComponent generatedId={generatedId} />
        <ParentComponent/> 
    ) 
}
```

`ParentComponent` renders its children:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div id={this.props.generatedId}>
            {this.props.children}
        </div> 
    )
}
```

And `ChildComponent` needs to locate its parent component in order to set a style:

```
render() {
    const myParentsScrollPosition = getWindow().document.getElementById(
        this.props.generatedId
    ).scrollTop;
    return (
        <div style={{ top: `${myParentsScrollPosition}px` }}>
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

The problem I am having is that both these components get rendered async and thus when `ChildComponent` checks `.getElementById(this.props.generatedId)` that element doesn't exist. It's still rendering.

How can I make `ChildComponent` wait until `ParentComponent` has rendered and therefore will be available in the DOM?

Alternatively I am thinking of other solutions but I'm not sure. For example, could I wait for the parent to mount before rendering the children, thus assuring it will always be available in the DOM?

Comment: I'd try to maintain the `scrollTop` value as state in the outer component (your first snippet). Then you can pass callback props to both the parent and child component, making this whole thing more imperative.

Comment: The React way is to use Refs. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38093981/6705349

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing this on render - it is not when elements appear on the screen (commited to DOM). You should be using `componentDidMount`
But then you might have a problem also, cause actually `componentDidMount` fires first on children and only then on parent, you should try anyway, since react will commit full DOM anyway, so when children's `componentDidMount` will work it should mean that parent also is already in the DOM (THOUGH I DO NOT RECOMMEND THIS).
I would suggest getting ref on your parent div or whatever in parent component, and from there getting it's scrollTop and passing to child directly in props.