# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot set property 'innerText' of null in React-hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, getelementbyid, weather, innertext

I want to make a weather app. But the string does not appear on the component I want.

How can innerText be used in React?

This is my Weather.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const Weather = () => {
  const API_KEY = '123456789';
  const COORDS = "coords";
  const weather = document.getElementById("weather");

  const getWeather = (lat, lng) => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lng}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
    )
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (json) {
        const temperature = json.main.temp;
        const place = json.name;
        weather.innerText = `${temperature}℃,\n ${place}`;
      });
  };
};
export default Weather;
```

This is the screen code for the weather to appear.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Weather from "../../Components/Weather";

const DetailPresenter = () => {
  
  return (
    <>
      <DetailContainer>
        <div id="weather">{Weather()}</div>  
      </DetailContainer> 
    </>
  );
};
export default DetailPresenter;
```

Comment: If you must refer to the element, you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38093981/10926702), otherwise I would go for the solution provided by @Drew Reese

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how react renders UI. We don't invoke the functions directly, we render them into the JSX "template" for React to invoke when necessary. Nothing is invoking your `getWeather` function to *actually* fetch the weather data. Also, direct DOM manipulation is an anti-pattern in react.

1. Save the text you want displayed into local component state.
2. Render it. Your `Weather` component currently returns undefined, which isn't valid for React, components ***must*** return valid JSX.

Weather

```
const Weather = () => {
  const API_KEY = '123456789';
  const COORDS = "coords";
  const [weather, setWeather] = React.useState('');

  const getWeather = (lat, lng) => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lng}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
    )
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (json) {
        const temperature = json.main.temp;
        const place = json.name;
        setWeather(`${temperature}℃,\n ${place}`);
      });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getWeather(......lat & long);
  }, []); // <-- run effect once on component mount

  return weather; // <-- string is valid JSX
};
```

DetailPresenter

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Weather from "../../Components/Weather";

const DetailPresenter = () => {
  
  return (
    <DetailContainer>
      <Weather /> // <-- render component, don't invoke
    </DetailContainer> 
  );
};
```