# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null?

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

This error came when I type first 15 lines of Javascript to animate my login page
and it was working. When I refreshed my page it started to show this error

It is my login page for my website made on ReactJS:

```js
export default function SignUp() {
        
            const sign_in_btn = document.querySelector("#sign-in-btn");
            const sign_up_btn = document.querySelector("#sign-up-btn");
            const container = document.querySelector(".container");
        
            sign_up_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
                container.classList.add("sign-up-mode");
            });
        
            sign_in_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
                container.classList.remove("sign-up-mode");
            });
            return (
                <>
                    <div class="container">enter code here
                        <div class="forms-container">
                            <div class="signin-signup">
                                <form action="#" class="sign-in-form">
                                    <h2 class="title">Sign in</h2>
                                    <div class="input-field">
                                        <i> <FaUser /></i>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field">
                                        <i> <FaLock /></i>
                                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn solid" />
                                </form>
                                <formclass="sign-up-form" >
                                    <h2 class="title">Sign up</h2>
                                    <div class="input-field">
                                        <i> <FaEnvelope /></i>
                                        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"
                                            required />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field">
                                        <i> <FaLock /></i>
                                        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"
                                            required  />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field">
                                        <i> <FaLock /></i>
                                        <input type="password" id="confirm-password" placeholder="Password Confirmation"
                                            required />
                                    </div>
                                    <button disabled={loading} type="submit" class="btn"> Sign Up</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="panels-container">
                            <div class="panel left-panel">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <h3>New here ?</h3>
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis,
                                        ex ratione. Aliquid!
                                    </p>
                                    <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-up-btn">
                                        Sign up
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <img src={Login} class="image" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel right-panel">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <h3>One of us ?</h3>
                                    <p>
                                        Already have an account?
                                    </p>
                                    <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-in-btn">
                                        Sign in
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <img src={register} class="image" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            )
}
```

Please help me to solve this error. Thank you.

Comment: This is not how you add handlers in react. Long story short by the time you execute query selector there is no DOM elements yet.

Comment: Then how can i correct it?

Comment: You need to use `createRef` function from React to access a dom element and you can only access those dom elements once the component is mounted. follow this doc https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: there is a similar question stack overflow already you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele

Comment: I would start with some basic React tutorials before reaching straight for refs since this is not their intended use case.

Comment: Can you guys please show me how to add ref and dom to this code sorry i am new to javascript.