# React onCLick() get buttons id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Well I´m new to React and I'm really struggling. I have a set of buttons, each one with id asigned from result of Http request. After onClick I would want to send that id to different part of application via Router. should be relatively easy?

```html
<Col>
  <div className="wrapper">
    <Button id={receptura.id} variant="primary" onClick={handleClick(this)}>
      Přejít
    </Button>{" "}
  </div>
</Col>
```

thats my button
and i want smth like this

```js
function handleClick(e) {
  alert(e.id);
};
```

whats the real solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the event in the onClick function like this:

```
onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}
```

Then in your handleClick function, you can get the id from the event target like this:

```
alert(e.target.id);
```

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-glade-cv7ce?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for a quick solution!  :)

Comment: No problem, best of luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

It's really no different from classic JS. Except, you'll want to access the target DOM element with `currentTarget` instead of `target` key.

```js
const id = e.currentTarget.id
```

Answer (score 0):

A more Reacty way to handle it would be to use `useRef()` but in this case you ready have the reference of the clicked button. You can directly do:

```
function handleClick(e) {
    alert(e.target.id);
}

// or if you already have receptura.id in the component simply try
function handleClick(e) {
    alert(receptura.id);
}
```

You can read more about refs in react here [How to access a DOM element in React? What is the equilvalent of document.getElementById() in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele)
or in official docs here
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html