# Trying to pass context to my WordPress block

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, wordpress-gutenberg

I am building a custom WordPress block using ES5, and I have a function in the edit to get the canvas:

```js
function imgclickHandler(event) {
  myPics = document.getElementById('myPics');
  context = myPics.getContext('2d');
  isDrawing = true;
  x = event.clientX;
  y = event.clientY;
  var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
  //alert(isDrawing);
}
```

The code is failing to find `myPics = document.getElementById('myPics');` the canvas in the HTML is coming out with the ID as `myPics`, but I don't think the JavaScript is getting the element.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to access DOM elements:

```js
function CanvasElement() {
    const canvasEl = useRef(null);
    
    return (
        <canvas ref={ canvasEl }></canvas>
    );
}
```

Then you can access the DOM element using `canvasEl.current`:

```js
canvasEl.current.getContext('2d');
```

See also: [How to access a DOM element in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele/38093981#38093981)

Comment: This is how I genereate my canvas to get a better idea of what im working with thanks wp.element.createElement( 
              wp.blockEditor.RichText.Content, {
                    tagName: 'canvas',
                    id: 'canvas',
                    width: '560',
                    height: '360',
                    onClick: imgclickHandler, 
                    onMouseMove: imgclickDrawHandler, 
                    onMouseUp: imgOffclickHandler 
                }

Answer (score 0):

This works as it should and get the context to the correct place

```
    function canvasonclickHandler(event) {
          canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
          context = canvas.getContext("2d");
          rect =canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
          xset = event.clientX - rect.left;;
          yset = event.clientY - rect.top;
          isDrawing = true;
          //alert("x: "+ x +"y: "+ y);

    }
```