# ComponentDidMount Doesn't allow me to access dom element(with specific ID)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, camunda

I was trying to access on of my dom elements using `getElementByID`, in `componentDidMount` Lifecycle hook in react. But it always gives `null`.
I have below component architecture.

app

- modeler(child1)
- properties panel(child2)

Now I need to access input field within properties panel using `getElementByID`. This properties panel element is based on third party Camunda properties panel.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using refs to access dom elements.

See this post for more information: [How to access a DOM element in React? What is the equilvalent of document.getElementById() in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele/38093981#38093981)

Comment: I can't edit the properties panel html. I just need to use 
input field their #camunda-id and get that element somehow.