# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am having this header which on scroll, I want to change the background to a different color.
The `navbar` variable returns null always. Why is it so? How can I do that?
The `transform:translateY` is just for a small animation on scroll.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navbar, Container, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'

import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap'

const Header = () => {

    const navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    let scrolled = false;

    window.onscroll = function () {
        if (document.body.scrollTop >= 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 200) {
            navbar.classList.add('color-nav');
            if (!scrolled) {
                navbar.style.transform = 'translateY(-70px)'
            }
            setTimeout(function () {
                navbar.style.transform = 'translateY(0px)'
                scrolled = true

            }, 200)
        } else {
            navbar.classList.remove('color-nav');
            scrolled = false
        }
    };

    return (
        <div id='navbar' >
            <Navbar fixed="top" className='navbar' collapseOnSelect expand="lg"  >
                <Container>
                    <LinkContainer to='/'>
                        <Navbar.Brand className='logo' >Logo</Navbar.Brand>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="me-auto">
                            <LinkContainer to='/services'>
                                <Nav.Link className='links'>Services</Nav.Link>
                            </LinkContainer>
                        </Nav>
                        <Nav>
                            <LinkContainer to='/login'>
                                <Nav.Link className='links'>Login</Nav.Link>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            <LinkContainer to='/signup'>
                                <Nav.Link className='links'>
                                    Sign Up
                                </Nav.Link>
                            </LinkContainer>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
        </div >
    )
}

export default Header
```

[image]

Comment: Usually my suggestion would be to check when the code is loaded. Firstly I would render the whole header and firstly then I would attach event listeners to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going about things in what I'd like to call, "against the React way". To  access the navbar element, you should be utilizing the `useRef` hook. This will give you an easy reference to that element through the components lifecycle.

On top of that, there are some other issues that need to be taken care of:

- The `scrolled` variable not being used with `useState`
- Your scroll listener not being set in a `useEffect`. Right now, your code would set a new listener on every re-render of your component. You want to just set it once.
- Your scroll listener not being cleaned up.

I've made some changes to the code that I would hope will fix this issue for you.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Navbar, Container, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";

import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";

const Header = () => {
  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false);
  const navRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (
        document.body.scrollTop >= 200 ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 200
      ) {
        navRef.current.classList.add("color-nav");

        if (!scrolled) {
          navRef.current.style.transform = "translateY(-70px)";
        }

        setTimeout(function () {
          navRef.current.style.transform = "translateY(0px)";
          setScrolled(true);
        }, 200);
      } else {
        navRef.current.classList.remove("color-nav");
        setScrolled(false);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="navbar" ref={navRef}>
      <Navbar fixed="top" className="navbar" collapseOnSelect expand="lg">
        <Container>
          <LinkContainer to="/">
            <Navbar.Brand className="logo">Logo</Navbar.Brand>
          </LinkContainer>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="me-auto">
              <LinkContainer to="/services">
                <Nav.Link className="links">Services</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
            </Nav>
            <Nav>
              <LinkContainer to="/login">
                <Nav.Link className="links">Login</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/signup">
                <Nav.Link className="links">Sign Up</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: This helped remove the error. But the effect needed is not being applied. The color has not changed but rather it simply disappears. The class is getting added, but not the effect..

Comment: I changed the code to use another ref, instead of `scrolled` with useState. Does this work?

Comment: It still is not working. Thanks for the effort. Found an alternative for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the navbar before it's rendered. That's why your variable is null. Try to use [Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to access a node element in React. [The answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-react-what-is-the-equilvalent-of-document-getele) can be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks. That really helped

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing it in react ways. there are many way's you could do this one of them being that is you can use useState hook keep the track of scrolled and update it on height change by this way  in jsx you can just use ternary oprator to change the className like

```
<div className = {scrolled ? "color-nav" : "something" }
```