# How to implement Pikaday to work in React

Tags: reactjs, pikaday

Refer to this topic 
[How can I use Pikaday with ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058477/how-can-i-use-pikaday-with-reactjs)

Here my configurations,

Importing

```
import Pikaday from 'pikaday'
import '../../node_modules/pikaday/css/pikaday.css';
```

Create reference

```
constructor (params) {
    super(params)
    this.myRef = React.createRef()
  }
```

Create pikaday object

```
componentDidMount() {
        new Pikaday({
            field: this.myRef.current,
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
            onSelect: null,
        });
    }
```

Rendering

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type='text'  ref={this.myRef} />
        ...
```

There is nothing occur when I clicked on the input!  Did I miss something?
Please help!

Comment: I think you copy/pasted the wrong code. You're using the original poster's, which is not working. refer to the answer

Comment: @Andrew I can't find working code on the post!  Appreciate much if you suggested any working one thanks.